# interference on R map with geojson file

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgdal, cartography

I downloaded the GeoJSON file from this link : https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/contours-iris/export/

and I plot it, but I have an interference polygone
[interference_polygon_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoA7d.png)

but on the web site, it shows the polygons and there is not this polygone :
https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/contours-iris/map/?q=gers&location=13,43.65999,0.5815&basemap=jawg.streets

I have ever tried to map with another file in shx from another website, and I have the same problem near the same town (Auch)

How can I delete it? Is it a problem with my R code?

Thank you for your help

```r
iris.poly2 <- readOGR(dsn="contours-iris.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")

ggplot()  + 
  geom_polygon(data=iris.poly2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=id), color="grey", size=0.1) +
  coord_map(xlim=c(0.4627843, 0.6773605), 
            ylim=c(43.58996 , 43.72575) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with replacing `group=id` by `group=group`

```r
ggplot()  + 
  geom_polygon(data=iris.poly2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="grey", size=0.1) +
  coord_map(xlim=c(0.4627843, 0.6773605), 
            ylim=c(43.58996 , 43.72575) )
```

`group=id` created a link between 3 polygons => the interference polygon